# How can I Store 2 data in an array retrieve with querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

5 days ago I looked into scraping, and how to recover data. The first thing I did once the basics of the code was laid out, was to do a querySellectorAll to retrieve all the elements with a specific class. It worked, so I stored the first element in my array, but an array with a single element is useless! So I tried to add the 2nd element, but the 2nd element does not want to be added to the array... I would like ALL the elements stored in the array to be strings. Here is my code:

```
const annoncesPrice = await page.$$("p[data-test-id]").innerText;
const annonces = await page.$$("p[data-qa-id]");
for (const annonce of annonces) {

  const annonceTitle = await page.evaluate((el) => {
    if (el) {
      return el.innerText;
    }
    return "";
  }, annonce)

  results.push({
    Titre_des_annonces: annonceTitle,
    price: annoncesPrice
  });
}
console.table(results);
```

I tried to unlock my code and replace it with the selector I wanted to assign to the 2nd element. It displayed what I wanted but the 2nd element was not aligned with the first element, it was placed much higher than the 2nd element. I also tried many other solutions, but all of them failed.

Comment: Can you share the URL for scrapping? I will help to understand your problem.

Comment: Hum, I tested several times and it's related to the code, not the URL, but if you stick to it, it's leboncoin

Comment: I tested  `https://www.leboncoin.fr` is blocked website from puppeteer. it needs to use puppeteer-extra to avoid it.